# Responsive issue in KendoGraph

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-chart, responsiveness

Facing issue in responsiveness of kendoGraph.

Here is the complete description of the  problem.
[Kendo Graph responsive issue](http://www.telerik.com/forums/responsive-issue-in-kendograph)

Can anybody please suggest a solution/fix.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call kendo.resize() on the containing DOM element to automatically resize all kendo widgets within the container.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/styles-and-layout/using-kendo-in-responsive-web-pages

```
var throttledResize = kendo.throttle(function () {
        kendo.resize($("#example"));
}, 100);

$(function() {
  $(window).on("resize orientationchange", function () {
       throttledResize();
  });
});
```

In this example the resize is throttled to no more than once every 100ms.

Updated **[DOJO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/acuKI)**